# Python Regex for Equity Option not Matching

Tags: python, regex, finance

I'm trying to create a regex to find option symbols in broker data. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_symbol) the format is:

1. Root symbol of the underlying stock or ETF, padded with spaces to 6 characters
2. Expiration date, 6 digits in the format yymmdd
3. Option type, either P or C, for put or call
4. Strike price, as the price x 1000, front padded with 0s to 8 digits

So I created this regex:

```
option_regex = re.compile(r'''(
(\w{1,6})            # beginning ticker, 1 to 6 word characters
(\s)?                # optional separator
(\d{6})              # 6 digits for yymmdd
([cp])               # C or P for call or put
(\d{8})              # 8 digits for strike price
)''', re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
```

But when I test it out I get an error:

```
import re

option_regex = re.compile(r'''(
(\w{1,6})            # beginning ticker, 1 to 6 word characters
(\s)?                # optional separator
(\d{6})              # 6 digits for yymmdd
([cp])               # C or P for call or put
(\d{8})              # 8 digits for strike price
)''', re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)

result = option_regex.search('AAPL  170818C00155000')

result.group()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-0273c989d990>", line 1, in <module>
    result.group()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Not sure if typo, but your regex only allows for one space after the ticker symbol, and your example string has two.

Comment: Thanks, missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [python documentation on `re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search):

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. **Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern**; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

Your code throws this exception, because the subroutine didn't found anything. Basically, you are trying to run `.group()` on `None`. It would be a good idea to defend against it:

```
if not result:
    ... # Pattern didn't match the string
    return
```

Your pattern doesn't match the string you typed in, because it has lengthier separator than what you assumed it to be: it has 2 spaces instead of one. You can fix that by adding a `+` ("at-least-once") to the rule:

```
(\s+)?                # optional separator
```